# Android - Adding external library to project

Tags: android, jar, external

I am having a lot of trouble adding the WEKA library to a project I am working on. I have followed several tutorials that explain how to do this including the Android Developers guide:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#addexternallibrary

and several of the postings on SO.

I have created a folder in my project with the weka.jar file, created a new library (adding the weka.jar file to the library) and included this library in my build path. I have also added the library under the "Order and Export" tab in the project properties.

I have also tried importing the jar file so that the actual contents of the jar are extracted into a directory in my project.

The end result of all of this is that my project is able to build correctly and without error, but when it comes time to run my code on the emulator I get the following exception:

04-10 22:52:21.051: ERROR/dalvikvm(582): Could not find class 'weka.classifiers.trees.J48', referenced from method edu.usc.student.composure.classifier.GaitClassifierImpl.

with J48 being the class I reference in my code.

Does anyone have any additional suggestions that I may have overlooked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WEKA is not going to work on Android without changes. `J48`, for example, requires the `java.lang.Cloneable` interface, which is not available in Android.

What you need to do is check out the WEKA source code from Subversion, add it to your project (removing the JAR file), compile it, and fix all the compile errors. There may be quite a few of these.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledgeable reply! I've found that it is possible to output Java code that replicates the tree structure of the trained classifier which does not use any Weka classes except for the Instance class (which I can easily replace). I'll just go with that workaround instead of trying to port Weka to Android haha.

Answer (score 5):

I just finished my first revision of https://github.com/rjmarsan/Weka-for-Android

Hope it helps!

Comment: Any more progress? Is weka proving usable for you?