# weka in android?

Tags: android, machine-learning, weka, classification

i need to run a program that classifies certain dataset values. on the computer i am using weka to classify the same and provide it to me but i need to implement the same on android. eclipse shuts down when i run the program(weka) by giving an error such as PermGen heap space. i read several forums and found the option of changing the value in the `--launcher.XXMaxPermSize` in the eclipse.ini file but i have not found any success. i just need to use the j48 classifier from weka, is there anything else existing that would do the work for me? or is there a workaround to fix the PermGen error in eclipse?

please guide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Adding external library to project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615381/android-adding-external-library-to-project)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just finished my first revision of https://github.com/rjmarsan/Weka-for-Android

Hope it helps.

Yes, the --launcher.XXMaxPermSize needs to be set higher.  1024 worked for me.

Comment: thank you for that...it will be of great help i am sure..but could you provide me the parameters you used in eclipse.ini these are what i used but it says Failed to start JVM 
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
-showsplash
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
am using a windows 7 32 bit version on a 62bit machine with 4gb ram on it, eclipse helios latest version...

Comment: I used -showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize1024m
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m

Comment: thank you so much RJ M.... it worked wonders! hey..could you please let me know how you managed to port it on Android..abdulraqeeb33@gmail.com

Comment: Time. I went through the entire library and ripped out all the SWING and AWT code I could find, until it compiled.  I needed it for a research project and was out of options.

Comment: RJM: Do you or anyone else have interest in continuing development of Weka for Android? I would be interested to contribute. I have experience with Android, but I am new to Weka.